# Apps script.. i dont know how do i make Copy sheet`s Specific name

Tags: javascript, excel, spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YAjq.png)

IF I PUSH THE BUTTON .
I WANT TO KNOW HOW CREATE NEW SHEET(COPY SHEET) NAMED NEXT + 1 DAY AND
THE CELL "C24" CONTENTS CHANGE TOO ?

0. BASIC SHEET NAME IS : 04/18/2022
1. I PUSH THE =BUTTON
2. NEW CREATE SHEET (ALL CONTENTS ARE COPY, BUT THE CELL "C24" DATE + 1 DAY
3. NEW CREATED SHEET`S NAME : 04/19/2022

Comment: Please don't write in CAPS, and please include all relevant content within your question, not as an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code help you to get the latest date form all sheet names and create a new name which is 1 day after the found sheet name.

```js
// get all the sheet names of a spreadsheet and turn them into numbers, if the sheet name cannot be parsed into an int, make it a 0.
const sheetNames = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
  .map(sheet => {
    const name = parseInt(sheet.getName());
    return isNaN(name) ? 0 : name;
  });
 
// find the biggest numbers of all sheet names.
const maxDate = Math.max(...sheetNames)+'';

// create a date object with the found number.
const maxDateObj = new Date(`${maxDate.slice(0,4)}-${maxDate.slice(4,6)}-${maxDate.slice(6,8)}`);

// add 1 day on it.
const nextDateArr = JSON.stringify(new Date(maxDateObj.setDate(maxDateObj.getDate() + 1))).split(/"|-|T/g);

// format the date object into your sheet name format.
const nextDate = [nextDateArr[1],nextDateArr[2],nextDateArr[3]].join('');

console.log(nextDate);
```

Comment: I revised the question, could you please look at it one more time? Please

Comment: Set a sheet with all the formats you want as the template, use apps script to copy the template to your current spreadsheet, than use .setName() to name the new sheet.